# Linking Specific Header Layout to TOC

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a BIG problem Connecting my Chapter Header Layout:

[image]

with the TOC in a good way. My chapter header layout is a number (in Styles "A_Chapternumber") on the first row and text (in Styles "A_Chaptertext") on the next row.

However when I try to insert a TOC I can't get the number and text to line up in the same row 1.Introduction, like it want it to:

[image]

[TOC_how_it_should_be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6srf.png).

I get something currently looking like this:

[image]

My document template : https://docdro.id/eViwQbZ

Answer (score 1):

I assume a) you have a Paragraph Style for the chapter number and a different one for the Title, and b) All chapters are consecutively numbered.

1) Make sure your Table of Content doesn't list the paragraph numbers, then right-click on the ToC and select `Edit Field...` from the pop-up menu:

[image]

2) In the list, select TOC, then click on the `Table of Contents...` button

3) Click `Modify`

4) Click on `TOC 1`, then on `Modify`

[image]

5) Click on ``Format...`and select`Numbering`

[image]

6) Choose the numbering format that suits you.

Your chapters should now all be numbered:

[image]